# Is there a better approach to reduce execution time of a long running quartz job?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have a cron job that will be triggered sometime in the night, that gets a large number of productIds around 100k from the DB, 
and get the productInfo for all of them from a service that takes around 700ms for an API call for  1 productId.

**CronJob**

```
public class GetProducts extends QuartzJobBean {

    @Autowired
    private ProductClient productClient;

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

        List<Long> ProductsIds = fetchAllProductIdsFromDb();

        Response<ProductClientResponse> response = null;

        for (Long productId : ProductsIds) {
            ProductClientRequestBody requestBody = new ProductClientRequestBody();
            requestBody.putIdInsideTheRequestBody(productId);
            response = productClient.getResult(requestBody).execute();

            if (response != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
                log.info("We have got successful response for {}", i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here  productClient is the Retrofit client of the service. 
So this job will take 5 hours technically to complete.

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#============================================================================
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=QuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#============================================================================
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=80
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=5
#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=20000
#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources
#============================================================================
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections=10
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery=select 0 from dual
org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount =10
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user=root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password=root
```

This is my quartz properties file. 
I wanted to know if there any better approach to get the ProductInfo for all the 100k products.

**One approach**

I schedule 100k jobs for all the ProductIds. and while quartz running on a clustered environment will schedule according to the instance available.

*org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=80* - this property states that in one instance of the service at most 80 threads can take up the jobs. **Is it?**
And if I have 2 instances running then at least 100-160 jobs can run concurrently. Am I correct in my approach? which can reduce the time by a huge margin.

**Is there any other better approach than this?**

Comment: You can use the quartz to schedule the job and can use the Executors to actually run the job.So in essence,you wont be holding the thread which is invoked by the quartz framework.

Comment: So you mean I should create one job as I am doing and inside that should use the executor thread. Is it?

Comment: Yes.So create the job and then delegate the responsibility to another class which will have the executor and can run your jobs in parallel.Adjust the number threads of the executors as per your requirement.This will make room for any other quartz scheduled task as the thread will be freed quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Note :- This is to demonstrate the approach the code can be further improvised(I have not tested the code and there can be syntactical errors)

public class ProductsJob extends QuartzJobBean {

```
@Autowired
private ProductClient productClient;

@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    List<Long> ProductsIds = fetchAllProductIdsFromDb();
    ProductsExecutor productsExecutor=new ProductsExecutor();
    productsExecutor.runTasks(ProductsIds);
}
```

}

public class ProductsExecutor {

```
private int threadPoolSize=10;
private ExecutorService executorService;

public ProductsExecutor()
{
    executorService =Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
}

public void runTasks(List<Integer> productIds)
{
    //Loop and execute the task and wait for them it necessary
    ProductsWorker worker=new ProductsWorker();
    worker.setProductId(productId);
     executorService.invokeAll(worker);
}
```

}

public class ProductsWorker implements Runnable {

private int productId;
@Override
public void run() {
    ProductClientRequestBody requestBody = new ProductClientRequestBody();
    requestBody.putIdInsideTheRequestBody(productId);
    response = productClient.getResult(requestBody).execute();

    if (response != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
        log.info("We have got successful response for {}");
    }

}

public void setProductId(int productId)
{
    this.productId=productId;
}

}

Don't forget to destroy your executor service as with each quartz run a new executor service will be created.Also you can add awaitTermination for all the submitted tasks.